# How to write the expression with multi-index notation?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, notation

I need some help for writing the following expression with multi-index notation, $$\sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_p=1}^n \frac{\partial^{2p}}{\partial x_{i_1}^2\ldots \partial x_{i_p}^2}f(x, \xi),$$ where $f:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb T^n\rightarrow \mathbb C$. The above expression is simply the Laplacian with respect to $x$ applied $p$ times. Any help will be valuable. Thanks

Comment: If $f \in C^{2p}(\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb T^n)$, then you can commute the partial derivatives and write it as $$\sum_{|\alpha| = p} (\partial^\alpha)^2 f(x, \xi).$$

Comment: I fixed what seemed like a typo ($\partial x^2_{i_p}$ was $\partial x^2_{i_n}$. Please check that this is correct. I added the (notation) tag too.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton At first sight I guess that works, but shouldn't there be a binomial coeficient inside the sum which would appear when you add the repeated terms?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen thanks for the improvements, I agree with them =D

Answer (score 1):

With @HenryT.Horton help I realized one could apply the multinomial theorem to get to the conclusion. The multinomial theorem says, $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^p=\sum_{|\alpha|=p}\frac{p!}{\alpha!}x^\alpha. $$ The expression I wanted to write with multi-index is just the Laplacian $\mathcal{L}_x$ with respect $x$ of the function $f$ applied $p$ times. Since $$\mathcal{L}_x=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2},$$ using the multinomial theorem above we get, $$\mathcal{L}_x^p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}\right)^p=\sum_{|\alpha|=p}\frac{p!}{\alpha!}\partial^{2\alpha}_x,$$ where $$\displaystyle \partial^{2\alpha}_x=\partial_{x_1}^{2\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_{x_n}^{2\alpha_n}=\frac{\partial^{2|\alpha|}}{\partial x_1^{2\alpha_1}\cdots \partial x_n^{2\alpha_n}}.$$ Thanks everybody for the help =D